# Joomla 3.9.13 - Error: Failed to start application

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, mysql, administrator, php7

I just installed version 3.9 joomla in local using xampp. Once the installation was finished correctly I tried to navigate the site and the backend. After loading a few pages, this annoying error appears:
"Error: Failed to start application: Table 'C:\xampp\tmp#xxxxx_xx.MAI' is read only"

The version of my xampp is: 3.2.4 with PHP 7.2.24
My joomla version is: 3.9.13

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: This topic should be in help of you: https://serverfault.com/questions/84890/cant-create-write-to-file-tmp-sql-xxxx-myi-errcode-13

Comment: Man i tried to visit your topic and i tried this solution of 777 permission for the folder: C:\xampp\tmp but without result. Any other help, please? Thanks for the moment!

Comment: The other problem usually happen with similar errors is the `htaccess` file in Joomla root directory. Something is wrongly defined, configured in that. You should check that thoroughly and we will see...

Comment: For the moment i'm working in local with my website so htaccess is renamed with .txt extension. I think that's not the problem because in local is not active, right?

Comment: No, you need `.htaccess` either way, it is a quite important file, not only for live servers.